# Feature Request: Notifications for question answers

Tags: feature-request

I often come across interesting new questions which don't have any answers yet. To further my knowledge, I would like to revisit these questions when they do have answers.

I would absolutely love it if a feature could be implemented where one "subscribes" to a question and gets some type of notification when either the question is answered, or an answer is accepted.

These notifications could form part of the other notifications in your inbox.

What I do at the moment is "favorite" questions with the hopes of (a) remembering to look at questions that I've previously "favorited" and (b) that the questions do in fact have an answer now.

I think such a feature could go a long way in promoting learning and knowledge sharing over and above the questions that you ask yourself.

Would love to hear what the community thinks of this.

Note: I posted this question on the Electrical Engineering meta here [Feature Request: Notifications for question answers](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/feature-request-notifications-for-question-answers). It could be useful for all sites though.

Comment: The list of duplicates is pointing to this being a good feature to implement....

Comment: You did notice you can favorite a question and then keep track of the questions in your profile by sorting them on activity, like so: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/116407/bitshift?tab=favorites&sort=activity

Comment: @rene I did but I think a feature as suggested would be a lot more helpful. Why do we need to manually keep track of things in this day and age?

Comment: Sure but on large sites like SO this might cost some resources. And I think there are workarounds available with the rss feeds so there isn't an high urgency on this. It might go on the 6 to 8 years to do list...

Comment: On the other hand, surely features like this could improve site engagement and thereby improve revenue?

Comment: I'm not voting on feature requests based on how it will influence revenue. I can't be bothered by that.